# Get Core Dump during JVM crash while using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, coredump

Our Java application uses native code(C++ so files) via JNI. The JVM crashes because of a SIGSEGV in the native code. Only the JVM crash log file hs_err_pid is created by JVM. We don't get any core files.

Is there a way(via JVM options) to also create core dumps along with the hs_err_pid file?

Also I want to collect core dump for the running Java process which is using JNI.

- JVM: 1.6.0_26
- OS: CentOS 4.9

Can someone help me here please?

Comment: This might help: [JVM options to create crash dump](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbmum)